# Show that $f = \chi_A$ a.e. for $A \subset E$ measurable, if $\int_E f^n = \int_E f < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $E$ is a measruable set and $f: E \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ is a non-negative function with $\int_E f(x)^n dx = \int_E f(x) dx < \infty$ for all positive integers $n$. Show that there exists a meaurable set $A \subseteq E$ such that $f = \chi_A$ a.e.

*My Attempt*

Define the measurable set $A = \{x: \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x)^n \text{ exists } \} $. Define $g(x) = \liminf_n  f(x)^n$, by Fatou's Lemma:

$$
\int_A \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x)^n dx \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_A f(x)^n dx = \int_A f(x)$$. Thus

$$
\int_A f-g \leq 0 \implies f = g \text{ a.e. }
$$

comparing the limit $g(x) = \liminf_n f(x)^n = f(x)$ for the cases $f(x) > 1$ and $f(x) \leq 1$ gives $f(x) = 1 \text{ or }0$

I know there is an error in the proof. Guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: $
\int_A f-g \leq 0 \implies f = g \text{ a.e. }
$? How does this follow?

Comment: You can argue that $f$ cannot be strictly greater than $1$ on a set of positive measure. After that you can take three sets where $f$ is $0$, in $(0,1)$ or $1$. Try to argue why the set on which $f$ is in $(0,1)$ has measure zero. More precisely, you can split the integrals in these sets and try to say something about each particular set (maybe by taking limits and applying convergence theorems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think it is valuable that you try to carry out Shashi's technical approach from the comments. Having said that, there is a nice trick that solves the problem: let

$$P(y) = y^2 (y-1)^2 = y^4 - 2y^3 + y^2.$$

By assumption

$$\begin{align*}
\int \limits_E P(f(x)) & = \int \limits_E f(x)^4 - 2f(x)^3 + f(x)^2 \\
& = \int \limits_E f(x) - 2\int \limits_E f(x) + \int \limits_E f(x) = 0.
\end{align*}$$

But $P(f(x)) \geqslant 0$ for $x \in E$, hence $P(f(x)) = 0$ a.e. on $E$. It follows that $f(x) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ almost everywhere and so $f = \chi_A$ a.e. for some measurable $A \subseteq E$.

---

Feedback on your approach: your definitions are overcomplicated. Note that for a fixed $x \in E$, the sequence $f(x)^n$ is a geometric sequence with a non-negative ratio $f(x)$. Such a sequence has a limit if and only if $f(x) \in [0, 1]$, so in fact

$$A = \{ x \in E : f(x) \in [0, 1] \}$$

and

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } f(x) = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Furthermore, it is unclear how you conclude that

$$\int f-g \leqslant 0$$

because the Fatou lemma give the opposite inequality. Lastly, it is also unclear how you conclude anything about $f$ outside $A$.

Comment: The kind of answer that opens a whole new way of seeing things. Amazing!

Answer (score 1):

$\lim t^{n}$ exists for every $t \geq 0$. (It may be $+\infty$, of course).

The hypothesis can be weakened to $\int_E f =\lim \int_E f^n$.

Note that $\int_E f =\lim \int_E f^n=\lim \inf \int_E f^n \geq  \int_{E\cap \{f>1\}} \lim \inf f^n\geq  \int_{E\cap \{f>1\}} \infty$ (by Fatou's Lemma). This proves that $\mu ( E\cap \{f>1\})=0$. In other words, $f \leq 1$ a.e. on $E$. Since $f^{n} \leq f$ a.e. we can apply DCT to get  $\int_E f=\lim \int_Ef^{n}=\int_E \lim f^{n}$. Noting that $f^{n}(x) \to 0$ if $f(x) <1$ we get $\int_E f=\int_{E\cap \{f=1\}} f$ or $\int_{E\cap \{f \neq 1\}} f=0$. Thus $f=0$ a.e on the set $E\cap \{f \neq 1\}$. In other words $f(x)\in \{0,1\}$ for almost all $x$. I will let you check that $f=\chi_A$ a.e. where $A=\{x: f(x)=1\}$.